# How to se up the Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ide, setting

Using Visual Studio 2015 community.

I commented two lines of codes.

```
//string Foo = "";      //  1st comment
////string Boo = "";    //  2nd comment
```

Then I blocked two lines and clicked uncomment icon at the command bar to delete 2 comment characters(//) in front of two lines at the same time.

```
string Foo = "";      //    1st comment
                //string Boo = "";  //  2nd comment
```

I have strange arrangement for the 2nd line. 
It moved automatically. 
I really do not want moving like this(I hate it).

What do I have to do ? 
This is what I want to have.

```
string Foo = "";      //    1st comment
//string Boo = "";    //    2nd comment
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I get from your question,
you should uncomment two times, it's not a serious problem.

Comment: Thank for the comment. First, It is the pain in the neck. Second, some people thinks the appearance is important. Lastly, You have to do extra action  (key typing or mouse click)-that is useless c.l.e.a.r.l.y.